# Why doesn't this β-hydroxycarboxylic acid undergo dehydration upon heating?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds

[image: 1-(hydroxymethyl)cyclohexane-1-carboxylic acid]

This is a [β-hydroxyacid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_hydroxy_acid), but why doesn't it get dehydrated to give an α,β-unsaturated acid on heating?

The mechanism which I think should occur is:

[image: Proposed mechanism]

Comment: What you've drawn isn't a dehydration, it's a retro-aldol reaction. You're losing formaldehyde instead of water. And your product isn't an alpha,beta-unsaturated acid.

Comment: @orthocresol I'm not sure of the mechanism that causes the conversion from beta hydroxy acid to alpha beta unsaturated acid. Could you give me a link? The mechanism in the image is just a guess...

Comment: Isn't the carbocation more likely to be captured by the carboxy group giving a 4-membered lactone?

Comment: @Waylander Which carbocation?

Comment: Depends on which O you think gets protonated first. If the carboxy group protonates the the alcohol OH can attack similar to acid-catalysed ester formation. The resulting B-lactone is a strained species,yet B-lactones exist.

Comment: @Waylander Why can't we just protonate the OH, and then decarboxylate leading to simultaneous loss of H2O, creating a new exocyclic double bond?

Comment: @SpaceSkiier  The decarboxylation will not proceed because there is no alpha proton to the carboxyl group

Comment: @Waylander To make things clearer, the final product I am talking about is methylenecyclohexane, which can be formed (at least theoretically) by simultaneous decarboxylation and dehydration of the last but one structure in Martin's answer. Kindly tell me why this cannot occur.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to obtain an α-β-unsaturated carbon acid from a β-hydroxy acid, you need a secondary or tertiary carbon in α position, because otherwise you would have to break a carbon-carbon bond, which requires a lot more energy then simply heating.

The mechanism is basically self catalysed, which is why this may happen easily with a little bit of heat. The acid may protonate intramolecular (or intermolecular) the hydroxy group. You have water as a nice leaving group, creating a carbocation, and abstraction of a proton in α-position leads to the olefin.

If you do not have that α-hydrogen, you are stuck with the carbocation. You might be able to obtain a lactone,like Waylander suggests, but I doubt this would easily happen with a little bit of heating, as spiro-compounds with four-membered rings tend to be quite unstable.

[image: mechanisms]

In your attempt you choose the less acidic hydrogen to transfer and then break a carbon-carbon bond resulting in a very unstable molecule which would rearrange to cyclohexanecarboxylic acid. I'd suspect you would need insane temperatures to overcome the activation barrier.

Comment: In the last but one structure you have drawn, we could've even removed CO2 and H2O in a single step, forming a new exocyclic double bond, leading to an alkene. Can you please explain why this would be incorrect?

Comment: @SpaceSkiier No I cannot. Sorry. You might want to [ask] a follow up question and someone else answers that.